# How to get the file name of a posted binary data using Golang?

Tags: go, gorest

I am posting a csv file as a binary file using Postman REST API client. I need to get the filename of the uploaded file.

[image]

Here is a simple example of posting a csv file as binary data and storing the binary data as a csv file.

```
package main

import (   //"fmt"
           "net/http"
           "os"
           "io"
           "log"
           "github.com/gorilla/mux"
       )

func uploadData(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    file, err := os.Create("hello.csv")
    _, err = io.Copy(file, req.Body)
    _ = err
}

func main(){
  router := mux.NewRouter()
  router.HandleFunc("/parse", uploadData).Methods("POST")
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router))
}
```

Comment: There is no filename associated with an HTTP request body.

Comment: @Flimzy I am attaching a csv file in my postman client. I am able to save the posted binary data to a csv file. How can I get the filename of the uploaded file?

Comment: The filename is not among the data that you're sending. You can't get data you don't receive from the client.

Comment: You can't because, as I already explained, there is no filename associated with an HTTP response body.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian, I am understanding it know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, there is no filename associated with a HTTP request body. You have to send the filename in your URL if you want to get the filename.

```
package main

import (   
           "net/http"
           "os"
           "io"
           "log"
           "github.com/gorilla/mux"

       )

func uploadData(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(req)
    file, err := os.Create(params["fileName"])
    _, err = io.Copy(file, req.Body)
    if err!=nil{
      log.Printf("Error while Posting data")
    }
}

func main(){
  router := mux.NewRouter()
  router.HandleFunc("/upload/{fileName}", uploadData).Methods("POST")
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router))
}
```

Comment: awesome solution =))

Answer (score 7):

You could use an encoding, such as `form-data`, which includes the filename to upload file with postman. This will help you can send `multipart/form-data` request to server. After that you can extract file name from server side.

[image]

From server side

```
func uploadData(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    _, header, _ := req.FormFile("demo")
    fmt.Println(header.Filename)
}
```

Comment: There's no reason that form-data, per se, is better than any other encoding. You could just as well use JSON, XML, a zip file, or literally _any other_ encoding that includes the filename

Comment: Total agree with you

Answer (score 1):

If you send file throught binary data then all body in http request will be filled with the binary of that data.

And as we mentioned, now http request body only contained with bytes from file that we send.

And filename information is not included into binary file, ex jpg, png, gif, or more.

Maybe the only way you can do this with binary is to guess what type of format it is using `bytes.Contain()`. Example png file must start with the same 8 bytes i.e. 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10, you can find more at here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures